# How to check file is cheched out by whom?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, tfs, visual-sourcesafe

How to check file is checked out by whom? I'm using Team Explorer in Visual Studio 2010

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use View -> Other Windows -> Source Control Explorer

or

Use an 3rd party tool like [TFS Sidekicks (http://www.attrice.info/cm/tfs/)](http://www.attrice.info/cm/tfs/)

Answer (score 3):

In source control explorer, find the file you're interested in, right click and go to properties.  In there you will see a status tab that shows you where the file is checked out to (user & workspace) and any pending actions on the file.

Answer (score 2):

See this images Notes : its related to vs 2008
step1:
[image]

step 2 : 
[image]